# Volume control reliability

Tags: vintage

Log potentiometers were the mainstay for volume controls in radios .I have seen values of 5 to 10K in early solid state radios .Valve radios would use 250K to 1 meg .Crystal cartridge record players would use 1 to 3 meg.Sure these ballpark values reflect the impedance levels .Given that impedance levels can now be easily dealt with by active means there is a choice of resistance values .What   log pot    resistance values give the best reliability? 10K? 100k ? 1K ?

Comment: Probably 100k because there is less likelihood of it overheating on standard/normal/average electric circuits. Other than that [MIL-HDBK-217](https://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/MIL-STD/MIL-HDBK-217F-Notice2.pdf) gives numbers but i didn't remember it saying the value was a factor in reliability.

Comment: I strongly doubt there's any significant difference in reliability, assuming they're used in the same conditions.

Comment: For extreme reliability, nothing can be moving. I'd use digital pots, with light-beam interruptions that indicate "less" or "more", the human-hand doing the light-beam interruptions.